# Rewrite Requests for Images to CDN URL with Varnish

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, cdn, varnish

I've got Varnish (3.0.3) sitting as a load-balancer/static cache in front of two web servers. I've got a CDN set up using Original Pull method. If I grab a URL from an image on my site manually, drop in the CDN address, I can verify that original pull is working and the image is pulled to the CDN and served.

My application is fairly complex and I'm testing this CDN to see if it significantly speeds up the web app, so I don't want to rewrite any of my php code to use the CDN images just yet.

What I'd like to do is set Varnish up to rewrite requests received for image files and pull them through the CDN instead of from the two Apache servers directly in my cluster.

I've read through the Varnish documentation and a couple howto's online about doing something similar, but I just can't get it to work properly and need a little help here.

Here are a couple different ways I tried doing this (edited for brevity):

```
sub vcl_recv {
  #if request is image, redirect to CDN
  if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|png)$") {
        set req.http.host = "cdn.domain.com/";
        error 750 req.http.host + req.url;

    }

 }
sub vcl_error {
  if (obj.status == 750) {
    set obj.status = 302;
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    return(deliver);
  }
}
```

That didn't work. It resulted in broken images everywhere, and anything that did show up was using the .webp extension, so it wasn't being processed by the condition above.

So I tried this:

```
 backend cdn {
         .host = "cdn.domain.com";
         .port = "80";
}
sub vcl_recv {
  #if request is image, redirect to CDN
  if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|png)$") {

      set req.backend = cdn;
      return(lookup);
  }
```

}

This showed some images on the page, but when viewing their source, they looked to be coming from the Apache servers (the domain name wasn't that of the CDN) and only about half the images were displaying...probably browser cache.

I'd love some input here, thanks guys.

Is there no way to use Varnish for this kind of redirect? Would I be better off setting nginx up in front of Varnish to rewrite requests to the cdn?

**UPDATE**:
Using both answers given below, I have the redirect working and an ACL in place to allow the CDN to pull images directly vs redirecting to itself. However, though I verified the ACL is allowing connection through by using my own external IP, the CDN isn't pulling new images from the server. It gives a 502 error (odd<) instead of pulling the image from the local server to the CDN and serving it. This is what the block of my vcl_recv looks like now:

```
acl cdn {
     "ip.of.CDN";
}

sub vcl_recv {
  #if request is image, redirect to CDN
  if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|png)$") {
        if(!client.ip ~ cdn){
           error 750 "http://cdn.domain.com" + req.url;
        }
    }

 }
sub vcl_error {
  if (obj.status == 750) {
    set obj.status = 302;
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    return(deliver);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely do this with Varnish quite easily - no need to setup nginx or anything. Actually your first solution is very close to doing the trick. It just needs a few modifications.

```
sub vcl_recv {
  #if request is image, redirect to CDN
  if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|png)$") {
        error 750 "http://cdn.domain.com" + req.url;
    }
}
sub vcl_error {
  if (obj.status == 750) {
    set obj.status = 302;
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    return(deliver);
  }
}
```

You forgot "http://" from your CDN URL, and you can omit the last slash from the host as all `req.url`s begin with /.

You also need to make sure that the `vcl_error` code is the first one that is run in `vcl_error()`. I.e. if you have multiple definitions of `vcl_error`, make sure that none of them get to deliver any output before the `if (obj.status == 750)` check is reached.

Bear in mind that this solution causes all client browsers to query your server first and then make another request to the CDN after the 302 redirect. This adds a significant delay to each image load, and is probably not the best way of determining if CDN improves your app performance.

**Update:** Regarding your problems with CDN showing 502 errors when trying to pull content from your origin. Relying on the remote IP address for determining the redirection is quite risky, as the CDN could very well use a number of servers to do the pull, and the addresses could change over time. That would make the VCL very laborious and error-prone to maintain.

Would it be possible setting up a unique virtual host for the CDN to use? For instance `originpull.domain.com` and setup the CDN so that it pulls content from that address instead of your primary `www.domain.com` address?

You could then modify the `vcl_recv()` as follows:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  #if request is image and request is not made from CDN, redirect to CDN
  if (req.http.host != "originpull.domain.com" &&
      req.url ~ "\.(gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|png)$") {
        error 750 "http://cdn.domain.com" + req.url;
    }
}
```

That would ensure that the requests from CDN will never be redirected.

Comment: thanks for the details here. Question about the 302 and delay though. So, typical flow for this setup: browser hits Varnish>passes to either of two servers>reads html>renders html and image from its source URL in the html. 

With a Varnish 302: browser hits Varnish>passes browser to server for html and CDN for images>renders html and images.

Is my understanding there correct? If so, this should be better than writing a redirect in httpd.conf or .htaccess because it happens earlier for the browser and images/html should come from the two sources in parallel? (CDN/local server)

Comment: and to follow my question with a question... Using mod_pagespeed and ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain to rewrite the html that is served..would this be less or more efficient than this Varnish method? The problem with MapRewriteDomain is it does everything, not just images and I don't want that, but for performance trials, where would this fall?

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, aside from the problem addressed by @arober11. When I activate this vcl, all the images show up as coming from the CDN. However, images that aren't on the CDN already aren't being pulled through it. I put the suggested acl in place, verified that it works by adding my own external IP there, but the CDN isn't pulling the images through for some reason. 502 errors

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in getting back to you. I'll address the first question first: rewriting the HTML is the best solution, since it cuts down the number of connections. The browser requests the image from the correct source immediately (e.g. http://cdn.com/pic.gif). When using 302 redirects, every request is 1) http://domain.com/pic.gif (302 response) 2) http://cdn.com/pic.gif (200 response).

Comment: As far as 502 errors are concerned, you should define a separate origin for your images that does not get redirected. At least for the CDN services we have used you can freely define origin URL for your images. This does not have to be public. So you could setup, for instance, http://static.domain.com/ to act as origin for your CDN alone, and skip the 302 redirect for the host by adding "&& req.http.Host != "static.domain.com" to the condition in vcl_recv()

Comment: No worries, it's the Holiday! 

Okay, I understand the 302 will add an additional pull, however, the mod_pagespeed method technically does rewrite the HTML. In general, you think that's an okay option as a temp solution?

Comment: For a temporary solution I think either one will do. I have no experience in running mod_pagespeed on a live site, so I can't tell what the performance impact might be. Since you are aiming to test real world performance gains, I'd just bite the bullet and change the app so that it serves images directly from CDN. Back in the days we created a specific cdnHost("pic.gif") function that outputs a full URL of pic.gif to make it easy for us to switch between our own static image server and a CDN provider, and thus benchmark the services.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the CDN pulling it's copy of the images from the site, and your not manually pushing images to the CDN. Aren't you missing a simple exclusion of the CDN network, from either your rewrite, or backend proxy? As the CDN needs to be able to directly pull a copy of the images, from your site to populate it's caches.

Been a while since I played with Varnish, and never an expert, but something along the following lines may work:

```
# Defnine the IP ranges of the CDN server.
acl cdn {
        "localhost";
        "11.22.33.0"/24;
}

...

    #if request is image, redirect to CDN, unless from the CDN
    if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|png)$") {
        if (!client.ip ~ cdn) {
            error 750 "http://cdn.domain.com" + req.url;
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: yea, tried the solution above and started getting 502 errors from the CDN cos it couldn't ever hit my server for the original image. I'm trying a mixed solution now..thanks for this